# How to set a structured variable with an expression

Tags: ansible

Is there any way in Ansible to set a variable to some structured value (e.g. a list or a dictionary) that is constructed from an expression?

For example, I have these variables:

```
all_flavours: ["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]
flavours_to_keep: ["chocolate", "banana"]
```

I want to evaluate the expression `all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep)` and store the resulting structured collection (list or indeed set) in the variable `flavours_to_drop`, so that for these values it's as if I had defined:

```
flavours_to_drop: ["vanilla", "strawberry"]
```

However, I can't find a syntax to do this. Here are my attempts:

## Attempt 1

```
flavours_to_drop: all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep)
```

This is simply interpreted as a string:

```
flavours_to_drop: "all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep)"
```

## Attempt 2

```
flavours_to_drop: {{ all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep) }}
```

This is an error because YAML interprets the "{" to mean a dictionary.

## Attempt 3

```
flavours_to_drop: "{{ all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep) }}"
```

This does the set difference correctly, but then converts it to a string, so I end up with:

```
flavours_to_drop: "set([\"vanilla\", \"strawberry\"])"
```

How can I evaluate the expression, but store the structured object straight back into a variable instead of converting it into a string?

I should add that I'm using Ansible version 1.6.2. Is this behaviour that has changed between Ansible versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting, etc. can be a little tricky.  You need to quote the filter in order for it to be parsed properly.  You can do it either as a var or in set_fact. You want something like this:

```
vars:
  all_flavours: ["vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]
  flavours_to_keep: ["chocolate", "banana"]
  flavours_to_drop_1: "{{ all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep) }}"

tasks:
  - debug: var=all_flavours

  - debug: var=flavours_to_keep

  - set_fact:
      flavours_to_drop_2: "{{ all_flavours | difference(flavours_to_keep) }}"

  - debug: var=flavours_to_drop_1

  - debug: var=flavours_to_drop_2
```

The result of the above is:

```
TASK: [debug var=all_flavours]     ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_flavours": [
        "vanilla",
        "chocolate",
        "strawberry",
        "banana"
    ]
}

TASK: [debug var=flavours_to_keep] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "flavours_to_keep": [
        "chocolate",
        "banana"
    ]
}

TASK: [set_fact ] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug var=flavours_to_drop_1] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "flavours_to_drop_1": [
        "vanilla",
        "strawberry"
    ]
}

TASK: [debug var=flavours_to_drop_2] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "flavours_to_drop_2": [
        "vanilla",
        "strawberry"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't get these results. I get the result I showed in attempt 3 - a string starting with the word "set". Is this behaviour that has changed between versions? I have version 1.6.2 in use here.

Comment: I used ansible 1.7.2 for the above, although I was also just able to test with ansible 1.6.6.  With ansible 1.6.6 flavours_to_drop_1 worked as expected whereas flavours_to_drop_2 was set to all_flavours, so it looks like there are bugs in the 1.6.x branch involving filters. You might want to upgrade to 1.7 or later if you can.